# Unable to Insert the same id for non primary column - Android Sqllite

Tags: android, sqlite

hi am trying to inset some values in to my `visits` table. the visit table has a column `schedule_id`which saves an integer value.

`Schedule_id` is not a Primary key.

My problem is when i try to insert a same id in to Schedule_id column, i am getting and error.

but if i try with unique value, that works.

Here is my code.

**Dbhelper class**

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public static final String TAG = "DBHelper";

    // columns of the schedule table
    public static final String TABLE_SCHEDULE= "schedule";
    public static final String COLUMN_SCHEDULE_ID = "schedule_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_SCHEDULE_NAME = "schedule_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_SCHEDULE_DATE = "schedule_date";

    // columns of the items table
    public static final String TABLE_ITEM= "items";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEM_ID = "item_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEM_VISIT_ID = "visit_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEM_NAME = "item_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEM_CHECK_STATUS= "item_check_status";
    public static final String COLUMN_ITEM_COMMENT = "item_comment";


    // columns of the employees table
    public static final String TABLE_VISITS = "visits";
    public static final String COLUMN_VISITS_ID = "visit_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_VISITS_SCHEDULE_ID = "schedule_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_VISITS_NAME = "visit_name";
    public static final String COLUMN_VISITS_TIME = "visit_time";
    public static final String COLUMN_VISITS_PLACE = "visit_place";
    public static final String COLUMN_VISITS_ADDRESS ="visit_address";
    public static final String COLUMN_VISITS_LOCATION_LAT = "visit_location_lat";
    public static final String COLUMN_VISITS_LOCATION_LNG = "visit_location_lng";
    public static final String COLUMN_VISITS_STATUS = "visit_status";

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "certisagent";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

    // SQL statement of the visits table creation
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_VISITS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_VISITS + "("
            + COLUMN_VISITS_ID              + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + COLUMN_VISITS_SCHEDULE_ID     + " INTEGER, "
            + COLUMN_VISITS_NAME            + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_VISITS_TIME            + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_VISITS_PLACE           + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_VISITS_ADDRESS         + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_VISITS_LOCATION_LAT    + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_VISITS_LOCATION_LNG    + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_VISITS_STATUS          + " INTEGER "
            +");";


    // SQL statement of the schedule table creation
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_SCHEDULE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCHEDULE + "("
            + COLUMN_SCHEDULE_ID        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + COLUMN_SCHEDULE_NAME      + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_SCHEDULE_DATE      + " TEXT NOT NULL "
            +");";

    // SQL statement of the item table creation
    private static final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_ITEMS = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ITEM + "("
            + COLUMN_ITEM_ID            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
            + COLUMN_ITEM_VISIT_ID      + " INTEGER, "
            + COLUMN_ITEM_NAME          + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
            + COLUMN_ITEM_CHECK_STATUS  + " INTEGER, "
            + COLUMN_ITEM_COMMENT       + " TEXT NOT NULL "
            +");";

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
        database.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_SCHEDULE);
        database.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_VISITS);
        database.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_TABLE_ITEMS);


    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w(TAG,
                "Upgrading the database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion);
        // clear all data
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SCHEDULE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_VISITS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ITEM);

        // recreate the tables
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

**VisitsDOA Class**

```
public class VisitsDAO {

    public static final String TAG = "visitsDAO";


    // Database fields
    private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;
    private DBHelper mDbHelper;
    private Context mContext;
    private String[] mAllColumns = {
            DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_ID,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_SCHEDULE_ID,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_NAME,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_TIME,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_PLACE,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_ADDRESS,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_LOCATION_LAT,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_LOCATION_LNG,
            DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_STATUS  };

    public VisitsDAO(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        mDbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
        // open the database
        try {
            open();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "SQLException on openning database " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void open() throws SQLException {
        mDatabase = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }

    public void close() {
        mDbHelper.close();
    }

    public Visits createvisits(int vid, int v_sid, String vname, String vtime, String vplace, String address, String vlat, String vlong, int vstatus) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_ID, vid);
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_SCHEDULE_ID, v_sid);
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_NAME, vname);
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_TIME, vtime);
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_PLACE, vplace);
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_ADDRESS, address);
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_LOCATION_LAT, vlat);
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_LOCATION_LNG, vlong);
        values.put(DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_STATUS, vstatus);
        long insertId = mDatabase
                .insert(DBHelper.TABLE_VISITS, null, values);
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DBHelper.TABLE_VISITS, mAllColumns,
                DBHelper.COLUMN_SCHEDULE_ID + " = " + insertId, null, null,
                null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        Visits newvisits = cursorTovisits(cursor);
        cursor.close();
        return newvisits;
    }



    public List<Visits> getAllvisits() {
        List<Visits> listVisits = new ArrayList<Visits>();

        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DBHelper.TABLE_VISITS, mAllColumns,
                null, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                Visits visits = cursorTovisits(cursor);
                listVisits.add(visits);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

            // make sure to close the cursor
            cursor.close();
        }
        return listVisits;
    }

    public List<Visits> getAllvisitsforSchedule(int id) {
        List<Visits> listVisits = new ArrayList<Visits>();

        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DBHelper.TABLE_VISITS, mAllColumns,
                DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_SCHEDULE_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                Visits visits = cursorTovisits(cursor);
                listVisits.add(visits);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

            // make sure to close the cursor

            cursor.close();
        }
        return listVisits;
    }

    public Visits getvisitById(int id) {
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DBHelper.TABLE_VISITS, mAllColumns,
                DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_ID + " = ?",
                new String[]{String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
        }

        Visits visits = cursorTovisits(cursor);
        return visits;
    }

    protected Visits cursorTovisits(Cursor cursor) {
        Visits schedule = new Visits();

        schedule.setvId(cursor.getInt(0));
        schedule.setVschID(cursor.getInt(1));
        schedule.setVname(cursor.getString(2));
        schedule.setVtime(cursor.getString(3));
        schedule.setVplace(cursor.getString(4));
        schedule.setVaddress(cursor.getString(5));
        schedule.setVlat(cursor.getString(6));
        schedule.setVlong(cursor.getString(7));
        schedule.setVstatus(cursor.getInt(8));


        return schedule;

    }

}
```

**Main Activity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private static final String TAG = "Main Activity";
    private ScheduleDAO mscheduleDAo;
    private VisitsDAO mvisitsDAO;
    List<Schedule> ListSchedule;

    // schedule variables
    public int schedule_id = 29;
    public String schedule_name = "Schedule 13";
    public String schedule_date = "2015-07-06";


    // visits variables

    public int visit_id = 42;
    public int visit_schedule_id =41;
    public String visit_name = "visit15";
    public String visit_time = "21:23";
    public String visit_place= "kilinochchi";
    public String visit_address = "vavuniya Street";
    public String visit_lat = "0.1115252";
    public String visit_long = "0.254255";
    public int visit_status = 0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      // insert_schedule();
       insert_visits();

        list_all_schedules();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

        Schedule schdul = ListSchedule.get(position);
        int sch_id = schdul.getId();
        String sch_stng_id =Integer.toString(sch_id);;
        String sch_name = schdul.getName();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, VisitsActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("sch_id", schdul.getId());
        intent.putExtra("sch_name", schdul.getName());


        Toast.makeText(this, sch_stng_id+" : "+sch_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivity(intent);
       // super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    }


    private void list_all_schedules(){

        mscheduleDAo =new ScheduleDAO(getApplicationContext());
        ListSchedule = mscheduleDAo.getAllschedules();

        ArrayAdapter <Schedule> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Schedule>(this, R.layout.list_schedules_layout, ListSchedule);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }


    private boolean insert_schedule(){
        mscheduleDAo =new ScheduleDAO(getApplicationContext());
        Schedule createdschedule = mscheduleDAo.createschedule(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(schedule_id)),
                schedule_name,
                schedule_date);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Schedule insert sucessfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return true;
    }

    private boolean insert_visits(){
        mvisitsDAO = new VisitsDAO(getApplicationContext());
        Visits createvisits =mvisitsDAO.createvisits(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(visit_id)),
                Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(visit_schedule_id)),
                visit_name, visit_time, visit_place, visit_address, visit_lat, visit_long,
                visit_status);
        Toast.makeText(this, "Visit insert sucessfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
07-07 09:11:28.957  11339-11339/lk.db.learn.databsetesting E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: lk.db.learn.databsetesting, PID: 11339
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{lk.db.learn.databsetesting/lk.db.learn.databsetesting.MainActivity}: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2429)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getInt(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:68)
            at lk.db.learn.databsetesting.data.VisitsDAO.cursorTovisits(VisitsDAO.java:156)
            at lk.db.learn.databsetesting.data.VisitsDAO.createvisits(VisitsDAO.java:76)
            at lk.db.learn.databsetesting.MainActivity.insert_visits(MainActivity.java:105)
            at lk.db.learn.databsetesting.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:59)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5442)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2493)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:166)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5584)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Cursor object is empty when calling `cursorTovisits` method

Comment: tnx @ρяσѕρєя K. I followed a Lynda tutorial and now got struck here can you tell me how can i fix this. plz.

Comment: i recommend to use ormsqlite instead of sqlite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert()` returns the SQLite `rowid` of the inserted row. Based on your create table statement, this value should match `COLUMN_VISITS_ID`, not `COLUMN_VISITS_SCHEDULE_ID`. The code you have now is looking for this value in the wrong column. The query finds no rows that match and returns an empty cursor, so you end up with a `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException` when you try to read from the cursor.

Change your query in VisitsDAO like so:

```
long insertId = mDatabase.insert(DBHelper.TABLE_VISITS, null, values);
Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DBHelper.TABLE_VISITS, mAllColumns,
        DBHelper.COLUMN_VISITS_ID + " = " + insertId, null, null, null, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your **cursorTovisits(Cursor cursor)** please check whether the cursor object has data.From the stack trace,it seems cursor is not having correct data or is not pointing to correct the location.It throws this **CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException**.From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException.html),this exception is thrown  when cursor is out of bounds.

To solve this error, use something like this:

```
if( cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() ){
    num = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("column name"));
}
```